# load javascript widget into wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Morning,

I have an affiliate external widget i need to place on a page in wordpress.

The official code i have been given loads external content within this page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.convert.co.uk/widget/mobiles.js"></script>
```

where you place the line of code is where the external content is displayed.
This works perfectly on a non-wordpress site.
Once loaded the content uses some jquery effects and ajax to swap the results.

If i add this code within a wordpress page, it loads the content fine but the jquery within the external content does not work.

many thanks.

I do not have access the external code to change.

Comment: are you using : wordpress.com or wordpress.org?

Comment: im using self-hosted wordpress.

Comment: then try install plugin eg. xyz html to make a snippet and try if it works. also, did you included the jquery plugin (.js file)?

Comment: also (if possible ) include jsfiddle / cdpn.io example.

Answer (score 0):

In the backend in the widget screen, drag and drop the text widget in the place where you need to display this external widget. Now, just add the code you have to that text widget and save it. You should now see your widget on the front end

Comment: the widget actually displays full screen. so it is placed within a page. I have pasted the code within the page, and it does go and get some results but the once loaded the jquery fails within this full page widget. I have the basics working its just the added jquery that fails within the external content. My theme is running jquery 1.10 and the external code brings in jquery 2.0.1 so not sure if it has a conflict with it.

Comment: I think that your jquery is not properly enqueued. I'm using the build-in library from wordpress, and the widget is loading just fine on my side, no problems. I think you need to go and have a look if your jquery is actually loading

Comment: Looking with firebug it appears the issue is with jquery-ui. I have looked at the generated code and the widget brings in jquery from <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> Im pretty sure it should have a http: on the front. It is then throwing a slider not a function error

Comment: You are correct, there should be a `http:` before the `//`. If you fix that, your problem should be solved